# Is there any difference on a table having PK and having and UNIQUE constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, primary-key

In TOAD, I can see my table said doesn't have PK. But there is an unique constraint for the PK candidate.

[image]

I try to make the field PK but toad said there is already a constraint for it on the table.

[image: I]

And can't remove the constraint because said someone else depend on it.

So should I leave it like that. Or go the extra mile disable all dependencies remove the unique constraint and create a PK?

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4941517587762

Comment: `UNIQUE` constraint accepts `NULL` value.  `PRIMARY KEY` can't accept `NULL`.

Comment: @Eric so if there is a difference why can't I create a PK if there is an UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: Is there a `NULL` value in the column?  If there's, then you can't create `PK`.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try to explain it. As Eric said, unique key constraint will accept (many) nulls for the constrained column.

First, create a table with unique key constraint (the one you have now):

```
SQL> create table test (id     number constraint uk_test unique,    --> unique key constraint
  2                     name   varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> -- This is the first record - no problem with it
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL> -- Uniqueness violated
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Foot');
insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Foot')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UK_TEST) violated


SQL> -- Let's insert some NULL values into the constrained column
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (null, 'Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (null, 'Big');

1 row created.

SQL> -- The result: not too pretty, eh?
SQL> select * From test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Little
           Foot
           Big
```

---

A step further: apply a new, NOT NULL constraint to the unique key column, so that it "acts" as if it were a primary key:

```
SQL> delete from test;

3 rows deleted.

SQL> -- add NOT NULL constraint
SQL> alter table test modify id not null;

Table altered.

SQL> -- The first record is OK
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL> -- Uniqueness violated
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Foot');
insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Foot')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UK_TEST) violated


SQL> -- This worked previously, but won't any longer because of the NOT NULL constraint
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (null, 'Foot');
insert into test (id, name) values (null, 'Foot')
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."TEST"."ID")
```

---

Finally, to show that now it acts as if it were a primary key constraint:

```
SQL> delete from test;

1 row deleted.

SQL> -- Let's drop the unique key constraint
SQL> alter table test drop constraint uk_test;

Table altered.

SQL> -- Add the primary key constraint (no duplicates, no nulls)
SQL> alter table test add constraint pk_test primary key (id);

Table altered.

SQL> -- The first record is OK
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Little');

1 row created.

SQL> -- Uniqueness violated
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Foot');
insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'Foot')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.PK_TEST) violated


SQL> -- Not null violated
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (null, 'Foot');
insert into test (id, name) values (null, 'Foot')
                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCOTT"."TEST"."ID")
```

Basically, now you got the same errors as previously, i.e. `primary key = unique key + NOT NULL`.

---

You can't create a primary key if the column is already constrained by the unique key - you already know that.

As you can't drop the unique key constraint (because foreign keys reference it), apply the NOT NULL constraint to that column.

Alternatively,

- drop all foreign key constraints
- drop unique key
- create primary key
- recreate foreign key constraints

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the UNIQUE constraint for a PK in three *easy* steps:

- Just create the PK with the same column(s).
- Then change all FKs to make them point to the PK constraint instead of the UNIQUE constraint.
- Finally, drop the UNIQUE constraint.

Easy.